# How do I get a div inside of an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

Ok, so I have an iframe, but I only want a particular div out of it. I cannot edit the original page.

How do I get that div? I'm trying to look around and nothing seems satisfactory.

Comment: You can only do this if the iframe resides on the same domain as the site from which you're trying to do that. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

Use your server as a proxy to fetch and extract the section of HTML that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ID of the div that you want, you can do a javascript or jquery search to pull out the div from the html code and display it. This doesn't need an iframe (an iframe displays an entire html document in a box).

Comment: This can only be done if the iframe's `src` is on the same domain as the parent page.